# Using pig with HBase to get timestamp of records

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I have been tasked with getting the timestamp for the data in an HBase table. If I do a `scan` on the table in the hbase shell, I can see the timestamp for a given row, e.g.,

```
scan 'mytable', {LIMIT => 1}
ROW                          COLUMN+CELL                                                                       
 00001000715ce3d569ee256153d column=0:, timestamp=1326362691000, value=1320073315600x600                       
 f31db629b                                                                                                     
1 row(s) in 1.9800 seconds
```

If I try to LOAD some data from this table in the grunt shell then I don't see the timestamp, only the value.

```
tableinput = LOAD 'hbase://imagestore-new' 
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('0: ', '-loadKey true')
AS (id:bytearray, thingy:chararray);
illustrate tableinput;
```

This gives me:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tableinput     | id:bytearray                         | thingy:chararray     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                | 0000bizrad8156b98bffa60d8968fba0f326 | {=1348461029160x130} | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm hampered by a serious lack of info about how to use HBaseStorage with pig; the only thing I can find is the API entry (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.html). I suspect there is a way to add it as a config in the call to HBaseStorage, similar perhaps to `'-loadKey true'`, but I don't know where to find this info. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can't do that right now. Here's the current list of available keys (you can see them in the constructor javadoc for HBaseStorage):

```
/**
 * Constructor. Construct a HBase Table LoadFunc and StoreFunc to load or store.
 * @param columnList
 * @param optString Loader options. Known options:<ul>
 * <li>-loadKey=(true|false)  Load the row key as the first column
 * <li>-gt=minKeyVal
 * <li>-lt=maxKeyVal
 * <li>-gte=minKeyVal
 * <li>-lte=maxKeyVal
 * <li>-limit=numRowsPerRegion max number of rows to retrieve per region
 * <li>-delim=char delimiter to use when parsing column names (default is space or comma)
 * <li>-ignoreWhitespace=(true|false) ignore spaces when parsing column names (default true)
 * <li>-caching=numRows  number of rows to cache (faster scans, more memory).
 * <li>-noWAL=(true|false) Sets the write ahead to false for faster loading.
 * <li>-minTimestamp= Scan's timestamp for min timeRange
 * <li>-maxTimestamp= Scan's timestamp for max timeRange
 * <li>-timestamp= Scan's specified timestamp
 * <li>-caster=(HBaseBinaryConverter|Utf8StorageConverter) Utf8StorageConverter is the default
 * To be used with extreme caution, since this could result in data loss
 * (see http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#perf.hbase.client.putwal).
 * </ul>
 * @throws ParseException
 * @throws IOException
 */
```

So as you can see, limiting scans by timestamps has been added, but no one has needed to actually return it. I don't suppose it would be hard to implement. Open a Jira? Maybe even post a patch? :)

Comment: thanks. i was starting to come to this conclusion, but left this question open just in case i was wrong about it. even worse luck, we are using a previous version that doesn't even contain the -min/max/timestamp flags, so we can't even filter by the value. :(